# Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForF0Debug'

Tags: gradle, nativescript

I am facing issues while running " `tns run android --emulator`". The error pertinent to the problem is attached. I am following the tutorial for native script, I could see many questions similar to this raised under angular studio, where they suggested to clean, not sure how to do this the native way, the build is failing has to be something with the gradle[image]

Comment: Try deleting the `build` dir in `platforms/android/`, additionally, do share what modules you've included in your app

Comment: tried deleting but was not of any help, this error happened while I tried the below step http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-1.html#14-running-your-app. I am blindly following the ateps in the tutorial

Comment: at the bottom of your image is the line "*What went wrong."... Could you post the lines below? Did you install the dependencies with `npm i` within your project root directory?